# How to use a method within a fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to write a fragment which has a method to set something in a TextView. So I have the following fragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
//    setText("set it to something");
    return view;
  }

  public void setText(String item) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    view.setText(item);
  }
}
```

This works fine. It shows the textview. I now want to edit the text in the textview programatically. I thought I'd first start with editing it from within the fragment. So I've got the method that should be able to do it. When I now uncomment `setText("set it to something");`it gives me an `InflateException: Error inflating class fragment.` and I have no clue why.

Would anybody know how I can solve this?

Comment: call your method in the onResume

Comment: @Waqas - Thanks for that. Works like a charm indeed! Other people also suggest other methods to do it within the onCreateView. Which one would be the best/correct way of doing this; in onCreateView or in onResume?

Comment: Doing it in `onResume()` will cause this method to be invoked every time fragment is paused and resumed which is bad because sometimes fragment is just paused and resumed (when a dialog is shown) in that case it is not a good idea to set the text again without any reason. I suggest you move this call to `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh i know my suggestion was a quick'n'dirty solution. Technically it should be called in onActivityAttached :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
class ... extends Fragment{
   private TextView _myTextView;

   onCreateView(...){
       //inflate view

       _myTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
       editText("blablabla");
   }


   private void editText(String text){
       _myTextView.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Ypu have to initialize all UI Elements in your onCreateView so you inflate from the view you are inflating!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in `onCreateView()` then do it like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    tv.setText("set it to something");
    return view;
```

}

The reason is that `getView()` can not be called before `onCreateView()` is returned.

**or** do it from `onViewCreated()`:

```
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    tv.setText("set it to something");
    // following will work too here
    // setText("set it to something");
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! Waqas also made a suggestion of doing it in the onResume. What would be the best/correct way of doing this, from within onCreateView like you suggest, or within the onResume method?

Comment: One more question; the reason that I want to have a dedicated method to change this text, is because I actually want to be able to invoke it from within the Activity. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Then you should call it from `onViewCreated()` or may be from `onActivityCreated()`. Doing it in `onResume()` will cause this method to be invoked every time fragment is paused and resumed which is bad because sometimes fragment is just paused and resumed (when a dialog is shown) in that case it is not a good idea to set the text again without any reason.

Comment: I tried creating onViewCreated() and onActivityCreated() within my fragment, but it complaints that these are not supertype methods of Fragment. Any idea/example of how to do this?

Comment: if you are using eclipse then just write `onView` where you want to insert the method, press ctrl+space and choose the method from options. same goes for `onActivityCreated()`.